# Conditional Expectation $E(X\mid X+Y=k)$ when Joint pdf is given.

Tags: conditional-expectation

$$f(x,y)=4 e^{-2(x+y)}$$ with  $x,y > 0$.

What would be $$E(X\mid X+Y= 4), ?$$
I tried by putting Y=$4$-X and then using usual formula of conditional expectation but that doesn't seem to be correct. Do we have to use transformation? I know here $X$ and $Y$ are independent so $X\mid X+Y$ would follow $Beta(1,1)$ or uniform $(0,1)$, so do we need to use this?

In general how do we proceed in these type of questions. It's simple in discrete cases but what about continuous ones?

Comment: Yes. but that's not the case if X+Y is given to be equal to some constant right?

Comment: I meant to say $E(X|X+Y)=\frac {X+Y} 2$ so $E(X|X+Y=k)=\frac k 2$.

Comment: X and Y are independent exponential with parameter 2 . So, X|X+Y follows Beta of first kind with parameters 1 and 1, implies Expectation is 1/2. Am I wrong here? Also The answer to this question is 4.

Comment: The answer cannot be $4$. It even goes against intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see $X$ and $Y$ are IID, and so by symmetry :

$\mathbb{E}(X|X + Y) = \mathbb{E}(Y|X+Y) = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}(X+Y|X+Y) \\ = \frac{1}{2} (X + Y)$

It follows $\mathbb{E}(X|X + Y = 4) = 2$